# How to create a file programmatically in a folder owned by root user

Tags: c++, linux, qt, file-permissions, qfile

I'm developing an application in Qt. I need to create a file in the location /usr/share/applications. The following is my code

```
  QDir::setCurrent("/usr/share/applications");
  QFile launcherFile;
  launcherFile.setFileName("aptana.desktop");
  int status = launcherFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
  QTextStream stream(&launcherFile);
  stream<<"Create file";
  launcherFile.close();
```

I'm not getting any error while debugging but neither does the file get created. I think it is a privilege issue because the user I'm logged in as does not have privilege to access this folder. I have seen other applications like Synaptic Manager prompting for the administrative password before continuing towards the application. Similarly is there anyway in which I can pop up the dialog box asking for the password and get the credential to create the file as root user? What other ways are there to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an approach to the general problem of asking for root priviledges and doing something. [Dio3 calls system() and passes the password to the cmd-level.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=0199fa191c227c02f1a623e54c4f84b7&p=6481499&postcount=4).
I don't know about a way to 'read a file through system and make QT-API happy, but you could change the file-permissions that way... but everyone doin' this to serious files should have  security nightmares :)

Comment: You could also use and configure appropriately `sudo` or `super`